# SAS data set "nonexistent"?

Tags: sas

Yesterday I renamed a SAS dataset using my OS. (instead of doing it within a SAS environment). Now, I can see it in my SAS explorer, but when I try to access it SAS tells me that it doesn't exist.  I was able to recall the name that I had given the set originally, change it back "manually" and then access it through the interactive SAS environment but, my question:

What the heck is going on here? Is this a flaw in my particular version of SAS or is this just how it is?

Comment: What name did you give the file?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What version of SAS are you running on which OS?  Where is the SAS dataset located>  Whats the filename and filetype of the file. Do you have a library in sas that access the path  of the folder where the dataset resides?

Comment: Are you using local SAS, or server-based SAS?  What product are you using to access it - base SAS/EG/Studio, or something like DIS?  Is this a metadata-registered table?

Comment: I suspect you gave it an invalid name, or added spaces or longer than 32 characters.

Comment: I gave it a valid name. (I changed the name of it from MASTER_SET.sas7bdat to MASTER_SET_OLD.sas7bdat. I'm running SAS on a virtual RedHat desktop (not by my own choice), it probably has something to do with that. I couldn't repeat the "issue" on my Windows machine. I'm going to check on Tom's suggestion that it might be a case thing.

The weird part that confuses me the most is that I could see the files in the SAS explorer window, but couldn't access them.

Thank you all for responding!

Answer (score 3):

Member names in SAS must be valid SAS names.  So you couldn't name your dataset `1979data.sas7bdat`.  You can relax some of the restrictions by setting the option `VALIDMEMNAME` to `EXTEND` and using name literals in your SAS code.

But also note that file names on case-sensitive file systems, like Unix, must be all lowercase.  So you couldn't use uppercase letters in the name of the file. So SAS would not see a file named `OldData.SAS7bdat` because if you tried to access a dataset named `xxx.OldData` it would be looking for a file named `olddata.sas7bdat` instead.